# Julia - Is there a way to make this in-place assignment function look better

Tags: julia, allocation

Consider this excerpt of code:

```
q = zeros(5,5);
x = rand(5,5);
function testFunc!(n, q, x)
    for i = 1:n
        q .= x.^2;
    end
end
```

I initialize `q` and update the values in `q` through an in-place assignment function. No matter how I choose `n`, the number of allocations is constant since I'm not creating anything new.

However, is there a way to write a function called `testFunc2` that looks like this:

```
q = zeros(5,5)
x = rand(5,5);
q = testFunc2(n, x)
```

such that the memory allocation is invariant to `n`.

I know that this looks silly, but in my actual code, I have numerous variables that are similar to `q` and I have a loop that updates them each iteration. I don't want the code to occupy excessive memory. If I write a function that looks like `testFunc2(n, x, q1, q2, q3, q4)`, it would look very cumbersome in terms of the syntax. Therefore, I want to be able to have `q1, q2, q3, q4 = testFunc2(n, x)` without having to worry about memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly, the simplest way is to use a closure:

```
let 
   q1 = similar(q)
   q2 = similar(q)
   global function testFunc2(n, x)
       for i = 1:n
          q1 .= x.^2
          q2 .= x.^2
       end
       return q1, q2
   end
end

julia> @btime testFunc2(10, $x)
  786.000 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime testFunc2(100, $x)
  7.476 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

As pointed by @Liso in the comment below, if we don't attempt to share the same memory between calls, the copy should be returned e.g. `return copy(q1), copy(q2)` instead of `return q1, q2`, then we'll still get constant memory allocation:

```
@btime testFunc2(10, $x)
  821.684 ns (3 allocations: 704 bytes)

@btime testFunc2(100, $x)
  7.326 μs (3 allocations: 704 bytes)
```

Anyway, choosing which method depends on corresponding use cases, [functor](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects-1) is a more flexible choice.

Comment: Results from more calls share same memory: `r1 = testFunc2(10, zeros(5,5));println(r1[1][1]);r2 = testFunc2(10, ones(5,5));println(r1[1][1])` -> `0.0 1.0` is it what was wanted?

Comment: @Liso that's why I wrote "If I understood correctly" ;), what I thought is just to illustrate the idea of closure. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if `q1, q2, q3, q4 = testFunc2(n, x)` looks much better than `testFunc2!(n, x, q1, q2, q3, q4)`, but you can do that type of transformation with a macro like this:

```
macro wrap(ex)
    outputs = ex.args[1].args
    ex.args[2].args[1] = Symbol(ex.args[2].args[1], "!")
    append!(ex.args[2].args, outputs)
    esc(ex)
end
```

which expands

```
@wrap q1, q2, q3, q4 = testFunc2(n, x)
```

into

```
(q1, q2, q3, q4) = testFunc2!(n, x, q1, q2, q3, q4)
```

Comment: Nice! :) If it is really about looking good then maybe something like `testFunc3!(n, x, q...)` could help too.